# Smooth controlled keyboard movement OpenGL

Tags: java, opengl, translation

I have an object that I am trying to translate with user keyboard input. When animating an object to move automatically, I have no problem with the object smoothly moving. Whenever I try adding user controlled movement however, I do not know of a way to control the translation of an object constantly instead of jumping the object x position spots. For example:

```
Display(){
    gl.glPushMatrix();
    gl.glTranslated(x,y,z);
    drawObject(gl);
    gl.glPopMatrix();
}

KeyPressed(KeyEvent e){
    char key = e.getKeyChar();
    if (key == w){
        x++;
   }
}
```

In the code above whenever I press "w", instead of continuously translating my object in the x direction, it will only move one spot each time that the user presses "w" based on whatever the value of x would be. What would I have to do in order to allow keyboard pressing to constantly translate an object by a certain amount while the button is held?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the user de-/presses a key, re-/set a flag "key is currently pressed". In the animation loop check for this flag and if it is set apply the movement animation.